# SQL Login failed for user ‘S-1-5-21-1482476501-1214440339-839522115-500' long id here

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have window service  which is running on the production server.The service hit the database server frequently for processing the record.Each day once it throw below error

> Login failed for user ‘S-1-5-21-1482476501-1214440339-839522115-500' 
>   Msg 18456, Level 14, State 1.

I wondering why it is showing long user name rather the sql username in the exception.The Server server version 2012.

Comment: That looks like a windows security identifier (SID); not a sql user.  I'd check to see if this had anything to do with windows authentication vs. SQL authentication.

Comment: I believe that is the user token that is generated by your AD/SQL authentication. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc759267(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: i have also check the server log in detail and found before this exception was raise a few minutes before there was log which say the client session was able to reuse the spid(session) but not sure why it is happening for couple of case in a day.I am not sure how to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Dan, yes this is SID but i am not sure what i need to check in the windows authentication vs SQL Authentication.Could you please help me.When the app build the connection string i pass username ,password and database name to connect to SQL server which resides in another machine and each day it throw an error with this long names. Does this long name are internal SID which server create on the machine which run the app or the machine where the SQL server run.

Answer (score 1):

That is a Windows SID as others have commented. I've had the same problem (trying to get an account name from a SID) and I have a little PoSH script that I use to do the translation:

```
param(
    [string] $sid = (Read-Host "Enter a SID")
)
$objSID = New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier ( $sid )
$objUser = $objSID.Translate( [System.Security.Principal.NTAccount] )
$objUser.Value
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [Login failed for user , Msg 18456, Level 14, State 1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2007/06/30/login-failed-for-user-xx-msg-18456-level-14-state-1.aspx) the specific `State 1` is encountered when:

> in connection string specify User as the NT account

So you have an application out there that uses/builds a connection string in which they specify their NT SID as a user name. If the app wishes to authenticate using integrated security it should use SSPI.

Comment: Remus , yes i have app which build connection string in which we specify the sql authentication credential only user name , password and build connecting string.But each day once i see the above error log on the server. As per the my knowledge this issue is becauase the connection pool is reset and existing connection  which the app used no longer exist as a result this issue is raised.However i am not sure this is the problem i don't have a way to diagnose it.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue and it was caused by contained databases. The fix in my case was to create a global user and assign that user to the database as db_owner instead of using the contained user account.

To create the global user, follow these steps:

- Login to SQL Enterprise Manager
- Expand the security node in the left hand tree
- Right mouse click on "Logins" and select "New Login..."
- Enter a Login name and a password
- Click "User Mapping" in the left hand pane
- Select your database in the right hand pane and then select the relevant role below. In my case I wanted the user to be a db_owner

Once you have created the new global login you will then need to update your application which is connecting to the database to use the new credentials.

This particular issue was acknowledged by Microsoft on 30/07/2013, see [Login failure with connection pooling in contained DB after connection has added contained user](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/772069/login-failure-with-connection-pooling-in-contained-db-after-connection-has-added-contained-user). They state "We are working on the issue and the fix will be in the next or future service pack", to be fair I haven't applied any cumulative hotfix packages since SP1 so this may already be fixed.